# Looping issue in for loop while avoiding duplicate entries

Tags: java, android, for-loop

In selected contact i am having duplicate values so that iam first taking copy of selected contact copy

```
    for(int q=0;q<selectedcontact.size();q++)
    {
        selectedcontactcopy.add(selectedcontact.get(q));
    }
```

and then Comparing two array list

```
    for(int r=0;r<selectedcontactcopy.size();r++)
        {
            for(int j=0;j<selectedcontact.size();j++)
            {
                if(r!=j && r<j)
                {

                    if(selectedcontactcopy.get(r).getLandLineNumber().toString().trim().equals(selectedcontact.get(j).getLandLineNumber().toString().trim()))
                    {
                    Log.i("hai",selectedcontact.get(j).getLandLineNumber().toString());
                    selectedcontact.remove(j);
                    j--;
                    }

                }
            }
        }
```

But the situation is that  first duplication is avoided then the arraylist won't compare the next consecutive values

Comment: selectedcontactcopy.remove(r);  inside if condition resolved my Problem. But this is not the proper way .      Actually i have to use set as said by below users

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bad way of doing a uniqueness check.  A better method is to make use of the functionality of `java.util.Set` - make sure your contacts implement Comparable and compare landline numbers, and then add them to the set and iterate over the set contents.

Set guarantees you uniqueness, and provides a far cleaner interface than nested for loops.

Answer (score 1):

Use `HashSet` to avoid repeated values from `ArrayList`,

Something like,

```
ArrayList arrayList = new ArrayList(); // Your ArrayList which contains repeated values
HashSet hashSet = new HashSet();
hashSet.addAll(arrayList);
arrayList.clear();
arrayList.addAll(hashSet);
```

The easiest way to remove repeated elements is to add the contents to a Set (which will not allow duplicates) and then add the Set back to the ArrayList.

Answer (score 0):

there is no need to create 2 lists for this.
create a HashMap with keys as the landline number and value as the whole contact object.

iterate over the list 'selectedContacts' and put all the elements into the hashmap.
finally, iterate over the hashmap created and store all the values in the hashmap into a list of contacts.

hope it helps.